# Zope Page Templates: calling a macro from a macro

Tags: macros, zope, zpt, template-metal

```
<span metal:define-macro="mymacro">
....
  <span metal:use-macro="mypath/macros/anothermacro">
  </span>
....
</span>
```

Basically it works, but it seems to create problems with permissions. Is this generally a bad idea?

Comment: *it seems to create problems with permissions*; what actual problems did you encounter? Macros within macros are fine, usually. Archetypes relies on this heavily, for example.

Comment: I use a mechanism similar to the Zope Product "Slave User Folder". I create users down in the object hierarchy with the same username but different roles. The nested macro (in fact 3rd nesting) is higher up in the hierarchy than the "slave". I get an Unauthorized Exception on the Template with the innermost macro (even if the "master" and "slave" users have both the role "Manager". The Exception is gone if I call the file instead of using the macro or if I delete the "slave" user.